# How does Twitter determine the spelling of trending hashtags?

Tags: twitter, hashtag

I am trying to build a hashtag system which is similar to Twitter hashtags for an app. However, I cannot figure out how to spell such tags, when grouping different spellings together.

As an example, when you use #abc on Twitter there might be different spellings like #abc, #Abc, #aBC, etc.
When a hastag is trending it is displayed with a certain spelling in the trending list, eg. #abC and groups all different versions.

How should I determine the "correct" spelling?

Comment: It could be that the hashtag with the most tags is taken as the correct and different variant (with relation to cases) just add up the number. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

I just built a hashtag system for my application and I'm not completely finished with it but my method was to get any posts that had a string of #*. Then parse that out with

```
GetHashes(t: string){    
var hashed = t.match(/#\w+/g);
if(hashed != null){
  hashed.forEach(element => {
    var unhashed = element.slice(0,0) + element.slice(1,element.length);
    this.hashTags.push(unhashed);
  });
}else{

}
```

}

Then once I have all the hashes, I simply do a replace to translate everything into lowercase. That is what I send to the database. I'm using Firebase so I'm denormalizing my data and duplicating it a ton so I store the entire content of the post under the tag in the database. This might seem like a lot of data storage waste but storage is cheap. Then I don't have to implement a search system like "ElasticSearch" or "Algolia" which is expensive. (I still need to for full text search but not for hashes saving me a lot of cash).

Then when I want to return all #* I simply find that reference in the Firebase Database and viola!

What I can't figure out is how to make my hashtags links that call a function dynamically. I've been using innerHtml but that makes everything a string.

Hope this helps a bit.